# Format System Output Messages via Python

Tags: python

I'm sending output message to email via subprocess check output. Output is not beautiful. For example "df -h" hasn't arranged view. Is there any way / library for this purpose?

Thanks

Comment: Every command you might want to call via `subprocess` has its own output format, and you have your own idea of what an "arranged view" should look like that might be different from anyone else. You need to have a clearer idea in mind of exactly what you want, and explain clearly how it's different from the original. It would help to show some examples.

Answer (score 0):

The output is in bytes format. You can decode it like so

```
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(['df', '-h'])
print(output.decode())
```

Comment: I want to format these messages like this: Filesystem                          Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rootrhel-root           7.4G  5.6G  1.8G  76% /
devtmpfs                             63G     0   63G   0% /dev
tmpfs                                63G  8.0K   63G   1% /dev/shm

Comment: well that is what this is doing, isn't it ? It prints it like it would if you had ran it in normal shell.